# How to make image open in new Tab after clicking on preview, Uploaded via custom form

Tags: magento2.3, image-upload, custom-admin-grid

I have created a custom form in admin and added a image upload field in the form.
When we edit a form having uploaded image in it, it shows preview of that image as small thumbnail.
[image]
After clicking on that preview image, image opens in same tab but I want it to open in new tab.
Can anyone help me here.

below is my code :
app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Edit/Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'file',
            'image',
            [
                'name' => 'file',
                'label' => __('File Upload'),
                'id' => 'file',
                'note' => 'Allowed File Types are .jpg , .jpeg, .png, .pdf ',
            ]
        );
```

Comment: did you get a solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I don't get the solution but I created a new fiwld woith same name and disaled it.
if ($model->getEntityId()) {
            $fieldset->addField(
                'file',
                'image',
                [
                  'label' => __('Attachement By Seller'),
                  'disabled' => 'true',
                ]
            );
        }
Hope it works for you as well.